# Updating an array stored in a VBA dictionary

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, data-structures, dictionary

I'm creating a data structure that uses nested dictionaries and a list at the lowest level. Here's a sample of my data:

```
Country, Customer, Purchased
US, Alan, Lawnmower
US, Alan, Hammer
US, Karen, Donkey
US, Simon, Mustang
MX, Carl, Lawnmower
MX, Alan, Donkey
...
```

The data structure I have in mind looks like `dictionary --> dictionary --> array` -- that is, `country --> customer --> purchased`. The plan is for there to be a new array per `dictionary --> dictionary` combination.

However, when I try to update the array, it seems that it is linked to all lower levels of the `dictionary --> dictionary` structure. That is, after the third row has been processed,  have the following situation:

```
US --> Alan --> [Lawnmower, Hammer, Donkey]
US --> Karen --> [Lawnmower, Hammer, Donkey]
```

... whereas what I'm expecting to see is:

```
US --> Alan --> [Lawnmower, Hammer]
US --> Karen --> [Donkey]
```

Here's the code I'm attempting to use:

```
i_p = UBound(purchased_array)

Redim Preserve purchased_array(i_p + 1)

purchased_array(i+p + 1) = item ' new item to add to the array

dataset(country)(customer) = purchased_array
```

However, this results in basically the same array being referenced by each lowest level of the `dictionary --> dictionary` structure.

Any thoughts on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: why `dictionary --> dictionary --> array`, why not `dictionary --> dictionary --> collection`?

Comment: I believed that a `collection` was a keyed data structure? Could I use it instead of an array?

Comment: sure, collection object support `.Add(Item, [Key])` method, but key is optional. so, you could omit it. In your case it would be much simplier to use collection instead array

Comment: If you have an array in a dictionary you must pull it out of the dictionary before you can modifiy it.  Then put it back in.

Comment: @TimWilliams when you say "pull it out" re: an array, what method are you talking about? I tried copying the array to a temp. array, and then inserting the temp. array, but had the same end result. Is there a method to set the array to NULL or similar?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have an array in a dictionary you must pull it out of the dictionary before you can modifiy it. Then put it back in.

```
Sub Tester()

Dim x As Long, y As Long
Dim dict As New Scripting.Dictionary
Dim d As Scripting.Dictionary
Dim arr

    For x = 1 To 3
        Set d = New Scripting.Dictionary
        For y = 1 To 3
            d.Add "nextkey" & y, Array("A_" & x & "_" & y, _
                                       "B_" & x & "_" & y)
        Next y
        dict.Add "key" & x, d
    Next x

    Debug.Print Join(dict("key1")("nextkey1"), ", ") '>> A_1_1, B_1_1

    'try to modify array while stored in dictionary...
    dict("key1")("nextkey1")(1) = "newValue1" '<<< doesn't work!

    Debug.Print Join(dict("key1")("nextkey1"), ", ") '>> A_1_1, B_1_1

    'have to pull it out of the dictionary if you want to change it...
    arr = dict("key1")("nextkey1")
    arr(1) = "newValue2"
    dict("key1")("nextkey1") = arr

    Debug.Print Join(dict("key1")("nextkey1"), ", ") '>> A_1_1, newValue2

End Sub
```

Comment: Okay, I think I follow what you've done. But what happens if you want to extend the `arr` array? That is, it is supposed to be a dynamic array, that grows/contracts depending on the number of entries in the purchased column.

Comment: Once it's outside of the dictionary you can use it like a regular array - if you want to extend it then that shouldn't be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Dictionary contains sets of pairs. Also, the keys list in Dictionary has to be unique. Within the top-level dictionary containing the relationship between Country & Customer, neither country nor customer is unique by that standard. So, I don't think dictionary is appropriate. Maybe you can try `Dictionary -> Array -> Array`.