# How to update values in VBA dictionary

Tags: vba, dictionary

StackOverflow,

The below subroutine is intended to:

- take a dictionary (ByRef), with value types = double, **OR**
- take a dictionary of dictionaries (ByRef), with sub-dictionary value types = double, and
- apply the calculation "ApproximateGeometricReturn" to each value within the dictionary.

While the code successfully runs, it fails to apply the calculation to the each value in the dictionary passed as an argument (ByRef).

Please suggest where I may have gone wrong.  I have also attempted to write this  as a recursive subroutine without success.

```
Private Sub ApproxiamteGeometricReturns(ByRef LogReturnDictionary As Variant)
  For Each Item In LogReturnDictionary.Items
    If TypeName(Item) = "Double()" Then
      For Each i In Item
        i = ApproximateGeometricReturn(i)
      Next
    Else
      Item = ApproximateGeometricReturn(Item)
    End If
  Next
End Sub
```

Any suggestions will be warmly received.  Thanks.

Comment: If you want to modify an array stored in a Dictionary, you first need to extract the array from the dictionary.  Once you're done modifying the array, you can put it back in the dictionary.   See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21940111/updating-an-array-stored-in-a-vba-dictionary/21941361#21941361

Answer (score 1):

```
Private Sub ApproxiamteGeometricReturns(ByRef LogReturnDictionary As Variant)
  For Each keyName In LogReturnDictionary.Keys
    If TypeName(LogReturnDictionary(keyName)) = "Double()" Then
      Dim arr As Variant: arr = LogReturnDictionary(keyName)
      Dim index As Integer
      For index = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
        arr(index) = ApproximateGeometricReturn(arr(index))
      Next
      LogReturnDictionary(keyName) = arr
    Else
      LogReturnDictionary(keyName) = ApproximateGeometricReturn(LogReturnDictionary(keyName))
    End If
  Next
End Sub
```