# Assign value to array

Tags: arrays, vba, dictionary

I have a `dictionary` and which also storing `array`. Here is the code and I am trying to assign some value to the array. But it always fails to assign value to the `array`. How can I solve this? Thanks

Code:

```
Dim dict As Dictionary
Set dict = New Dictionary
For i = 1 To fruitList.count
    dict .Add fruitList(i), Array(0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
next
dict(apple)(0) = 100 //however, the first index in the array always equals to 0
```

Update:
Or I should ask in this way. Isn't the way I add `array` as value in `dictionary` wrong?

Comment: Are you trying to do this in VB.NET? or VBA? Your tag says VBA.

Comment: @braX excel vba

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
Sub addArray2Dict()
    Dim a: a = Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0) 'Here declare and store the array,
                                                   'you can do it any other way
                                                   'there is no difference if you do it here or
                                                   'in the loop
    Dim b 'Just for testing porpuse
    Dim oDict As Object 'Because I use “Microsoft Scripting Runtime” can use earle binding
    Set oDict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Dim i 'iterator

    'Store numbers and letters inside the dictionary
    'BUT in the index number 5 I will store the array
    For i = 1 To 20
        If i = 5 Then
            oDict.Add i, a
           'oDict.Add i, Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0) 'As I said, this is the same as the line above.
        Else
            oDict.Add i, Chr(66 + i) 'Storing just letters in every key(integer)
        End If
    Next i

    b = oDict(5) 'Here I take the array from the Dictionary, and store it inside b,
    Debug.Print b(3) 'Here just print the 3th (number 4)  elemente of the array
                     'remember the array is:
                     '
                     ' array( 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 ) right!
                     '        0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9   <<< with that index
                     '
                     ' if i want the 3th value i will get the number 4 in my example.
End Sub
```

[image]

[Use this as a reference](https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-dictionary/)

> “Microsoft Scripting Runtime” (Add using Tools->References from the VB
>   menu)

As I understand your code could be this:

```
Sub Test()
    Dim fruitList(1 To 5) As String
    Dim i
    Dim B
    fruitList(1) = "apple"
    fruitList(2) = "banana"
    fruitList(3) = "melon"
    fruitList(4) = "orange" 'Love oranges!
    fruitList(5) = "kiwi" 'Love Kiwi too!!!!
    Dim dict As Dictionary 
    Set dict = New Dictionary 
    For i = LBound(fruitList) To UBound(fruitList) 'here you use the bounds of the array,
                                                   'instead .count, here won't work
        dict.Add fruitList(i), Array(0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
    Next
    B = dict("apple") '(0) = 100 'however, the first index in the array always equals to 0
    B(0) = 100 'Here! You take the array FROM the dictionary and store it inside B
               'Just do it!
    B(1) = 200
    B(2) = 300
    B(3) = 500
    B(4) = 1000000
    Debug.Print B(0) 'Testing! This will print in the console your value (100).
    dict.Remove "apple" 'Remove the array
    dict.Add "apple", B 'Return the new array!
End Sub
```

You can't change the values of an array stored inside an Dictionary (in VBA). It is better to take away de array and change the values, and after that, if you need it to, stored back in the dict.

Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21941361/3212973) If [Tim Williams](https://stackoverflow.com/users/478884/tim-williams) says you can't it is because nobody can!

Comment: Thanks for your brief explain. However, how can I assign a value to b(3) ? Coz my case is when I do oDict(5)(3) = 10, b(3) still return 4

Comment: Ok, there is your code working. You need to take the array from the dict, Check this answer: [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21940111/updating-an-array-stored-in-a-vba-dictionary)

Comment: AND! if this helps you, please... set the answer! Send some love please!

Comment: Just change some comments in the correction of your code.

Answer (score 0):

This can all be found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/arrays/

```
Dim myArray(arraySize) As ArrayType
```

or

```
Dim myArray = New ArrayType() {Item1, Item2, ...}
```

So, in practice, it should look like this:

```
Dim companies(3) as String
companies(0) = "Microsoft"
companies(1) = "Google"
companies(2) = "Amazon"
```

or:

```
Dim companies = New String() {"Microsoft", "Google", "Amazon"}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but how can I add array as value in dictionary?

Comment: Note that that's the `.Net` link (the tag is VBA, not Vb.net).

Comment: This can be found here http://vb.net-informations.com/collections/dictionary.htm

`Dim dict As New Dictionary(Of KeyType, ValType)()`
In practice, it would be:

`Dim compAndCEO As New Dictionary(Of String, String)()
compAndCEO.add("Amazon", "Jeff Bezos")
`

Comment: @WILLIAM If this solves your question, could you please mark my response as the answer?

Comment: @FadiFarag I tried, not work. It gave me an "expected end of statement error" when I just declare "Dim dict As New Dictionary(Of KeyType, ValType)()". What I actually want to do is declaring a dict as key: "apple" value: Array(100, 100, 100, 100, 100)? I have no idea how to make use your answer

Comment: This does not work for VBA. VBA is not the same thing as VB6 or VB.NET