# Differentiating Repeating Items with Scripting Dictionary

Tags: excel, vba, dictionary

I am trying to join two tables based on container numbers.

The containers can repeat after three months which lumps all the quantities together.
Table1 has the container numbers along with their processed dates.
Table2 has the container numbers along with the quantities and invoice date.

I think I can match the container number and the correct amount of quantities by looking at the delta between process date and invoice date with a maximum of 30 days since a container cannot repeat for a minimum three months.

The code uses the scripting dictionary to write Table2 with container, quantities, and invoice date. Table1 then loops through with the process date.

My issue is that when it loops through it only captures one row vs summing the multiple rows of quantities.

```vb
Sub joinTables()

Dim wLo As ListObject
Dim cLo As ListObject
Set wLo = wmsWks.ListObjects("Tbl2")
Set cLo = clincWks.ListObjects("Tbl1")

Dim containerDict As Object
Set containerDict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

'fill the dictionary with WMS data, summing qty
Dim i As Long
For i = 1 To wLo.ListRows.Count
    Container = wLo.ListColumns("Container").DataBodyRange(i).Value
    allocQty = wLo.ListColumns("AllocatedQty").DataBodyRange(i).Value
    invQty = wLo.ListColumns("InvoiceQty").DataBodyRange(i).Value
    invDate = wLo.ListColumns("InvoiceDate").DataBodyRange(i).Value

    If containerDict.exists(Container) Then
        containerDict(Container)(0) = containerDict(Container)(0) + allocQty
        containerDict(Container)(1) = containerDict(Container)(1) + invQty
    Else
        containerDict(Container) = Array(allocQty, invQty, invDate)
    End If
    
Next i
    
'headers
joinWks.Cells(1, 1).Value = "Container"
joinWks.Cells(1, 2).Value = "AllocatedQty"
joinWks.Cells(1, 3).Value = "InvoicedQty"
joinWks.Cells(1, 4).Value = "InvoiceDate"
joinWks.Cells(1, 5).Value = "ProcessDate"

'loop through clinc data
For i = 1 To cLo.ListRows.Count
    Container = cLo.ListColumns("Container").DataBodyRange(i).Value
    procDate = cLo.ListColumns("Process Date").DataBodyRange(i).Value

    If containerDict.exists(Container) Then
        allocQty = containerDict(Container)(0)
        invQty = containerDict(Container)(1)
        invDate = containerDict(Container)(2)
      
        'check date difference within 30 days
        If Abs(procDate - invDate) <= 30 Then
            j = joinWks.Cells(joinWks.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
            joinWks.Cells(j, 1).Value = Container
            joinWks.Cells(j, 2).Value = allocQty
            joinWks.Cells(j, 3).Value = invQty
            joinWks.Cells(j, 4).Value = crDate
            joinWks.Cells(j, 5).Value = procDate
        End If
    End If
Next i

Set containerDict = Nothing

End Sub
```

Sample Table1 with ProcessDate
[image: Sample Table1 with ProcessDate]

Table2 which I need to sum quantity:
[image]

Comment: Would help to also show table1

Comment: `containerDict(Container)(0) = containerDict(Container)(0) + allocQty` FYI you cannot update an array contained in a Dictionary - you must first pull the array out into a variable, update it, and then replace the array stored in the dictionary with the edited version.  See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21941361/478884

Comment: Container  Process Date
ABCD2231967  1/30/2023
ABCD2231967  5/19/2022

Table setup would be similar to above

Comment: You can edit your question so we can more easily read that...   https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77332502/edit

Comment: In your screenshot the dates are all the same for a given "group" - are they al really that consistent?

Comment: you have `ListColumns("InvoiceDate")` but the screenshot shows `CreateDate`

Comment: @TimWilliams For the most part yes, there will be times where there are multiple invoices however should never exceed 30 days

Also the CreateDate is also the invoice date. sorry for the name changes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot update an array contained in a Dictionary - you must first pull the array out into a variable, update it, and then replace the array stored in the dictionary with the edited version.

For example:

```
Dim tmp
'...
'...

If containerDict.exists(Container) Then
    tmp = containerDict(Container)  'copy to local variable
    tmp(0) = tmp(0) + allocQty      'update local copy
    tmp(1) = tmp(1) + invQty
    containerDict(Container) = tmp  'copy to dict
Else
    containerDict(Container) = Array(allocQty, invQty, invDate)
End If
```

Your array only captures the first date for each container though, so this approach will end up summing all dates together...

**EDIT**: I'd be inclined to take a different approach here.  You can query the source tables using SQL and perform the join/aggregation more easily/flexibly.

**EDIT2**: some changes to deal with files opened from SharePoint or other HTTP location by first saving a local temp copy

For example:

```vb
Public Sub JoinandSum()

    Dim oCon As Object, rs As Object, conn As String
    Dim wb As Workbook, tblA As ListObject, tblB As ListObject, sql As String

    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set tblA = wb.Worksheets("Input").ListObjects("Table1")
    Set tblB = wb.Worksheets("Input").ListObjects("Table2")
    
    conn = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
                        "Data Source=" & QueryPath(ThisWorkbook) & ";" & _
                        "Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;"";"

    sql = " select a.Container, a.[Process Date], sum(b.[Invoice Qty]) as TotQty, " & _
          " min(b.[Invoice Date]) as MinInvDate, max(b.[Invoice Date]) as MaxInvDate " & _
          " from " & TableRef(tblA) & " a, " & TableRef(tblB) & " b " & _
          " where a.Container = b.Container and " & _
          " abs(a.[Process Date] - b.[Invoice Date])<30 " & _
          " group by a.Container, a.[Process Date]"
    
    Set oCon = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    oCon.Open conn
    Set rs = oCon.Execute(sql)
    PutResults rs, wb.Worksheets("Input").Range("J1")
    
    rs.Close
    oCon.Close
    
End Sub

'When using ADO to query a workbook, figure out if it's opened from
'   an HTTP path, and if it is then make a temporary local copy as the data source
'Note: does not currently handle unsaved workbooks... 
Function QueryPath(wb As Workbook) As String
    Dim p As String
    p = wb.FullName
    If UCase(p) Like "HTTP*" Then
        p = Environ("temp") & "\" & wb.Name
        ThisWorkbook.SaveCopyAs p
    End If
    Debug.Print "Using file" & vbLf & p
    QueryPath = p
End Function

'return a string referencing a listobject, for use in sql
Function TableRef(lo As ListObject)
    TableRef = "[" & lo.Parent.Name & "$" & lo.Range.Address(False, False) & "]"
End Function

'Populate a range with the content of a recordset, including the field names
Sub PutResults(rs As Object, rng As Range)
    Dim f, i As Long
    For Each f In rs.Fields
        rng(1).Offset(0, i).Value = f.Name
        i = i + 1
    Next f
    If Not rs.EOF Then rng(1).Offset(1).CopyFromRecordset rs
End Sub
```

**EDIT3**: Containers in the first table which are not in the second table  -

```
sql = " select distinct a.Container from " & TableRef(tblA) & " a " & vbLf & _
          " where not exists " & vbLf & _
          " (select 1 from " & TableRef(tblB) & " b where b.Container=a.Container) "
```

Sample inputs/output:
[image]

Comment: Thanks Tim! Its giving me a "Not a valid file name" error. COuld it be bc I'm using office365?

Comment: Is your file saved locally (non-HTTP) ?  If you open it from sharePoint you'll first need to save it locally.

Comment: Got it, it works now! Is there any variation where I could have the connection run if the file stays on sharepoint?

Otherwise, this awesome Tim. Appreciate you!

Comment: See edits above - checks to see if the file is on an HTTP path, and if Yes creates a local copy to act as a data source for the query.

Comment: Nice! Way to go Tim

Comment: Tim- got one last question, would I do a left join if I wanted to record which containers were on table A but not on table B? Thanks

Comment: See Edit3 for example.

Answer (score 2):

Create dictionary from Table1 with key as container and value as another dictionary of process dates for that container.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub joinTables()

    Dim wLo As ListObject, cLo As ListObject
    Dim arReport, i As Long, j As Long, r As Long
    Dim dict
    
    Dim id As String, dtInv, dtProc
    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    
     ' containers
    Set cLo = Sheet1.ListObjects("Table1") 'clincWks
    ReDim arReport(1 To cLo.ListRows.Count - 1, 1 To 5)
    
    For i = 1 To UBound(arReport)
        id = cLo.ListColumns("Container").DataBodyRange(i).Value
        If Len(id) > 0 Then
            dtProc = cLo.ListColumns("Process Date").DataBodyRange(i).Value
            
            If Not dict.exists(id) Then
                dict.Add id, CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
            End If
            
            dict(id)(dtProc) = i
            arReport(i, 1) = id
            arReport(i, 5) = dtProc
        End If
    Next
    
    ' loop through clinc data
    Dim quInv, quAlloc
    Set wLo = Sheet2.ListObjects("Table2") 'wmsWks
    With wLo
        For i = 1 To wLo.ListRows.Count
            id = .ListColumns("Container").DataBodyRange(i).Value
            dtInv = .ListColumns("InvoiceDate").DataBodyRange(i).Value
            quInv = .ListColumns("InvoiceQty").DataBodyRange(i).Value
            quAlloc = .ListColumns("AllocatedQty").DataBodyRange(i).Value
            ' find nearest proc date for container id
            For Each dtProc In dict(id)
                If Abs(dtInv - dtProc) <= 30 Then
                    j = dict(id)(dtProc) ' report row
                    arReport(j, 2) = arReport(j, 2) + quInv ' InvoiceQty
                    arReport(j, 3) = arReport(j, 3) + quAlloc ' AllocatedQty
                    arReport(j, 4) = dtInv ' InvoiceDate
                End If
            Next
        Next
    End With
    
    ' report
    With Sheet3
        .Range("A1:E1") = Array("Container", "InvoiceQty", "AllocatedQty", "InvoiceDate", "ProcessDate")
        .Range("A2:E2").Resize(UBound(arReport)) = arReport
    End With
    
    MsgBox "Done", vbInformation
    
End Sub
```